# Python: AttributeError and challenges on web scraping

Tags: python, html, web, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from "http://www.landwatch.com/Philippines_land_for_sale/Land"; what I need are the address and price info. My methodology is using the beautiful soup module in python. I got stuck when I inspected the html page, also with coding. May some of you give me a bit hint so I can move on. Basically the web inspection indicated that the information I need is from div class = clear property left, and here are the code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.landwatch.com/Philippines_land_for_sale/Land'

#Openning up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page_html,'lxml')
g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "clear property left"})
for item in g_data:
  print(item).contents[0]
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the address and price info is in the `<a>` element of `<div class="propName">` under `<div class="clear property left">`, you can find deeper inside the `g_data`, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
my_url = 'http://www.landwatch.com/Philippines_land_for_sale/Land'
link=requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'lxml')
g_data =soup.find_all('div',class_='clear property left')
for item in g_data:
    address_price_info = item.find("div",{"class":"propName"}).find('a').text
    print(address_price_info )
```

Output will be:

```
   Cebu City, Philippines  1185000, PHP
   Tagaytay, Philippines  $116,000
   Quezon City, Philippines  $2,837,000
   Sta Rosa Laguna, Philippines  15500, PHP
   Makati, Philippines  $5,947,826
   Puerto Princesa City, Philippines  $358,813
   Carcar, Philippines  35000000, PHP
   Lipa City, Philippines  $57,750
   Makati, Philippines  6400000, PHP
   Taytay, Philippines  $2,300,000
   Taguig, Philippines  $504,208
   Taguig City, Philippines  $13,760
   Quezon City, Philippines  58000000, PHP
   Cebu City, Philippines  7799030, PHP
   Las Pinas, Philippines  $468,000
```

**Update:**

If you use chrome to inspect the address and price info, it will show you the location:

```
<div class="clear property left">

    <div class="margintop">

        ...             
        <div class="propName"> #Here is the address and price info
            <a href="/Cebu-City-Philippines-Land-for-sale/pid/119211639" onclick="WC('119211639', '-1');"> &nbsp; Cebu City, Philippines <BR/> 1185000, PHP</a>
        </div>


            <div>PAYMENT SCHEMES:\r\rReservation Fee : P20,000 (non refundable)\r\r1. SCHEME 1\rCash - 100% with the following discounts\r* 10% for 7 days payment\r* 8%...&nbsp;</div>

        ...

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tiny.D!!! One more quick question how did you find the price and address info is in <a> of propName?? I could not even see that.